# how to make trees with different tables cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have this structure...

grandpa hasMany children, children hasMany kids

can i make a tree of those 3 tables? I think my question really is, can i use only those tables without creating another one to make a tree structure?

Comment: Why not make 1 table person? 
Each row would have its children and parents...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can, because a tree behavior is for 1 table.

But you could use a table `persons`, `persons_kids`

```
+--------------------+
|   persons          |
+--------------------+
|  id  |  Name       | 
+--------------------+
|  1   |  Grandpa    |
+--------------------+
|  2   |  Dad        |
+--------------------+
|  3   |  Me         |
+--------------------+
|  5   |  MyChildren |
+--------------------+
|  4   |  MyBrother  |
+--------------------+

+--------------------+
|   persons_kids     |
+--------------------+
| parent_id | kid_id | 
+--------------------+
|    1      |   2    | // Grandpa -> Dad
+--------------------+
|    2      |   3    | // Dad -> Me
+--------------------+
|    2      |   3    | // Dad -> MyBrother
+--------------------+
|    3      |   5    / // Me -> MyChildren
+--------------------+
```

Both `parent_id` and `kid_id` would point to `person_id`
You could do differents model that points to differents foreign key in the `persons_kids` table.

Good luck.

For more info see the [Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1339/Tree)